# Why does my Java code not execute System.out.println?

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I'm using the Netbeans IDE, and it has not detected any bugs. I'm just curious as to why this code is not executing. FYI this is Exercise 4.4 from "Think Java: How to think like a computer scientist."

```
import java.lang.Math;
public class Exercise {
    public static void checkFermat(int a, int b, int c, int n){

        if ((Math.pow(a, n))+(Math.pow(b, n))==(Math.pow(c, n)) && n!=2){
            System.out.println("Holy smokes, Fermat was wrong!");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("No, why would that work?");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        int a = 8;
        int b = 4;
        int c = 10;
        int n = 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: ...because you never call `checkFermat`?

Comment: I don't agree with the downvotes.  If the poster is (apparently) learning Java, this is a perfectly reasonable question to ask.  Just because the answer is obvious to an experienced programmer, does not mean it is obvious to a beginner.

Comment: @EricJ. [Chatroom/meta effect](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1773626#1773626)

Answer (score 8):

You never call the `checkFermat` function from `main`. The only code that is executed in a Java program is the code inside of `main`. Any other methods that you define are only executed if they are called from within main. Therefore, your code should read:

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class Exercise {
    public static void checkFermat(int a, int b, int c, int n){

        if ((Math.pow(a, n))+(Math.pow(b, n))==(Math.pow(c, n)) && n!=2){
            System.out.println("Holy smokes, Fermat was wrong!");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("No, why would that work?");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        int a = 8;
        int b = 4;
        int c = 10;
        int n = 3;

        checkFermat(a, b, c, n); //call the method here
    }
}
```

Also, your local variables `a`, `b`, `c`, and `n` are not automatically applied to the function. You must pass them as arguments explicitly. Note the `a`, `b`, `c`, and `n` variables inside of `main` are completely separate from the `a`, `b`, `c`, and `n` in `checkFermat`: they are separate variables because they are declared in separate functions.

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't know what I would do without you guys. :)

Answer (score 2):

Because you are not calling the `checkFermat` method in main

Try,

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        int a = 8;
        int b = 4;
        int c = 10;
        int n = 3;
        checkFermat(a,b,c,n);

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Update the main method :

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        int a = 8;
        int b = 4;
        int c = 10;
        int n = 3;
        Exercise.checkFermet(a,b,c,n);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To execute **System.out.println()** statement you need to call **checkFermat** function without calling it it will never take that statement to execute but when you will call this the main function will invoke **checkformat** and execute code written inside that function...

Answer (score 0):

You just call the method checkFermat like bellow

Exercise.checkFermat(a,b,c,n) or

Exercise e = new Exercise();
e.checkFermat(a,b,c,n);